# append value of data attribute to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to extract the values of date-res and data-ref with jquery and append it to it's div.

```
<div id="grid">
<div class="item blue" date-res="8" date-ref="13" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>D</div>
<div class="item green" date-res="9" date-ref="10" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>E</div>
<div class="item green" date-res="2" date-ref="7" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`.append(val1,val2)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/),

```
$('#grid div.item[data-res][data-ref]').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append($this.data('res'),$this.data('ref'));
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p5XGz/)

Your html contains wrong attribute names instead of `data-` so use,

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="item blue" data-res="8" data-ref="13" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>D</div>
    <div class="item green" data-res="9" data-ref="10" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>E</div>
    <div class="item green" data-res="2" data-ref="7" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `.data()` you can get the value if uts attribute

you need to change html into this from `date-res` to `data-res` :

```
 <div id="grid">
    <div class="item blue" data-res="8" data-ref="13" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>D</div>
    <div class="item green" data-res="9" data-ref="10" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>E</div>
    <div class="item green" data-res="2" data-ref="7" data-groups='["all", "letters", "blue", "square"]'>F</div>
    </div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item').each(function(index){
        var res = $(this).data('res');
        var ref = $(this).data('ref');
        $(this).append(res).append(ref);
    });
});
```

---

if you can't change html try this:

```
$('.item').each(function(index){
    var res = $(this).attr('date-res');
    var ref = $(this).attr('date-ref');
    $(this).append(res).append(ref);
});
```

Comment: in case of var res = $(this).data('res'); you won't get anything as you've mentioned in html date-res. please change html to "data-res" then you'll get the res values. same is applicable for "data-ref" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').each(function(index){
    var res = $(this).attr('date-res');
    var ref = $(this).attr('date-ref');
    $(this).append(res).append(ref);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U5FvG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: I hope this works perfectly for you.

```
$("#grid").find('.item').each(function(index,element){

    var res=$(this).attr("date-res");
     var ref=$(this).attr("date-ref");
        $(this).html("res value="+res+"  ref value="+ref);


    })
```